# time average for specific time range in r

Tags: r, datetime, filter

I am trying to extract average values of all variables between 0 to 40 minutes every hour.

```
dput(head(df))

structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1563467460, 1563468060, 
1563468660, 1563469260, 1563469860, 1563470460), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), date = structure(c(1563467460, 1563468060, 
1563468660, 1563469260, 1563469860, 1563470460), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), Date = structure(c(18095, 18095, 18095, 
18095, 18095, 18095), class = "Date"), TimeCtr = structure(c(1563467460, 
1563468060, 1563468660, 1563469260, 1563469860, 1563470460), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), MassConc = c(0.397627, 0.539531, 0.571902, 
0.608715, 0.670382, 0.835773), VolConc = c(175.038, 160.534, 
174.386, 183.004, 191.074, 174.468), NumbConc = c(234.456, 326.186, 
335.653, 348.996, 376.018, 488.279), MassD = c(101.426, 102.462, 
101.645, 102.145, 101.255, 101.433)), .Names = c("DateTime", 
"date", "Date", "TimeCtr", "MassConc", "VolConc", "NumbConc", 
"MassD"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I've tried so far..

```
 hourly_mean<-mydata %>% 
  filter(between(as.numeric(format(DateTime, "%M")), 0, 40)) %>% 
  group_by(DateTime=format(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H")) %>%
  summarise(variable1_mean=mean(variable1))
```

But it gives me a single average value for the whole period. Any help is very much welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert `DateTime` , use `ceiling_date` with hourly unit to round `Datetime`, extract minutes from `DateTime` and `filter` to keep minutes which are less than 40, `group_by` `hour` and take `mean` of values.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(DateTime = ymd_hm(DateTime), 
         hour = ceiling_date(DateTime, "hour"),  
         minutes =  minute(DateTime)) %>%
  filter(minutes <= 40) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(ends_with("Conc")), mean)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2019-08-0810:07", 
"2019-08-0810:17", "2019-08-0810:27", "2019-08-0810:37", "2019-08-0810:47", 
"2019-08-0810:57", "2019-08-0811:07"), class = "factor"), MassConc = c(0.556398, 
1.06868, 0.777654, 0.87289, 0.789704, 0.51948, 0.416676), NumbConc = c(588.069, 
984.018, 964.634, 997.678, 1013.52, 924.271, 916.357), VolConc = c(582.887, 
979.685, 963.3, 994.178, 1009.52, 922.104, 916.856), Conc = c(281.665, 
486.176, 420.058, 422.101, 429.841, 346.539, 330.282)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Instead of "summarise_at.." term, I put "summarise(mass=mean(mass)), since my actural column names are not variable1, 2, etc, but "mass" , etc. Finally, it is not working, showing an error message " 0 rows. All formats failed to parse. No formats found."..

Comment: @user2928318 The error seems not because of `summarise` but `ymd_hm`. Try `df %>%
  mutate(DateTime = ymd_hm(DateTime))` does it work or shows `NA` with same warning? Can you try `as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` does it work or returns `NA` as well. You might have some different data format then shown. Can you post `dput(head(mydata))` ?

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. The first term "df %>% mutate(DateTime = ymd_hm(DateTime))." is working but the next term seems not working. My DateTime is already POSIXct format. Please find my data update above. Just column names are modified.

Comment: @user2928318 It would be helpful if you could post `dput` instead because when I copy-paste your data it seems to work for me. See updated answer, you can use my data and check if it works without error for you?

Comment: My post is updated. I just posted a sample of whole data set before. Error is " `.fn` must be a length 1 strin".

Comment: @user2928318 `mydata %>%
  dplyr::mutate(hour = ceiling_date(DateTime, "hour"),  
                minutes =  minute(DateTime)) %>%
  filter(minutes <= 40) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(ends_with("Conc"), starts_with("Mass")), mean)
` this works for me on your updated data. Or you might need `floor_date` instead of `ceiling_date`.

Comment: filtering is working, but there is something wrong in "summarise" term. Still see ".fn must be a length 1 string"... I will further figure out why. Many thanks, Ronak! :)

Comment: I just tried in R version 3.4.0 instead of 3.4.4., your code is not working! beautiful! It was definately the version issue related to some packagues?! Many thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I see, you should consider upgrading R. I am using `R version 3.6.1`.